# Rails Tutorial (M.Hartl) 3rd Edition, Chapter 8, How to unlock a database by closing a rogue `rails console`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am in [*chapter 8.4.1*](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-remember_token), after generating a migration I tried running:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

But was given the following error:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked:

#followed by a long list of paths/filenames and line numbers...
```

I know this is probably because I exited a terminal without properly exiting a `rails console --sandbox` session. But how do I find and close this `rails console` session?

Comment: you might want to accept one as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your terminal console type (making sure you are in your Rails app directory):

```
$ ps aux
```

Then you should see a list of processes, amongst them something similar to:

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
ubuntu     49527  0.0  0.0 482924   620 ?        Sl   Jan29   0:00 rails_console --sandbox
```

Take a note of the `PID`, in this case `49527`, then run the following in the command line:

```
$ kill 49527
```

Now running your migration `$ bundle exec rake db:migrate` should work.

Comment: actually `ps aux | grep rails` is what you should be executing.

Comment: Also, `top` is another good command to checkout running process.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, running `ps aux` will return list of all running processes. its not going to give you just the process from `rails`. also, you dont have to be in Rails app directory in order to run it.

Answer (score 1):

try running `$ ps aux | grep rails` from the terminal.

should return something like this:

```
username   68924   0.0  1.5  3166032  62168   ??  S     8:49PM   0:00.16 rails_console    
username   68900   0.0  0.1  2472884   3420 s003  S+    8:48PM   0:00.62 /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby bin/rails c
username   68708   0.0  0.2  2535772   6396 s000  S+    8:20PM   0:03.16 /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby bin/rails s
```

Since the process has to be killed in this case, try to kill it forcefully with the command

`$ kill -9 PID`