# Sinatra not running on localhost

Tags: ruby, sinatra, webrick

I have a number of Sinatra apps that have worked fine in the past. Now none of them will load to localhost. I have entered the same information in my browser to access them (http://localhost:4567), but nothing comes up. The page just hangs for a very long time...upwards of five minutes. Usually I kill the process to end it.

I tried this with Webrick and Thin, neither worked. Here is the most recent output for Webrick:

```
[2016-02-06 00:13:07] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-02-06 00:13:07] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]
== Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2016-02-06 00:13:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=8118 port=4567
^C== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
[2016-02-06 00:13:41] INFO  going to shutdown ...
```

The shutdown hangs after this too and I usually do CTRL-Z, then kill -9 [pid] to stop it.

I've looked around quite a bit on SO for answers, but I'm still stuck. I wasn't able to find a Webrick log in the /var/log folder, so I wasn't sure where to start looking for errors. This is driving me crazy because I know that my apps were working fine before and I need to write a new Sinatra app quickly.

The only thing that has changed is that I updated the gem to 2.5.0...it's possible that this is the problem, but I wasn't able to find any evidence of other people encountering this problem with that gem.

Has anyone run into this before? If not, any suggestions on where I can see the error log?

Comment: Don't know anything about Sinatra, but maybe you have rogue servers running? see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156280/rails-tutorial-m-hartl-chapter-8-how-to-unlock-a-database-by-closing-a-rogue/35156281#35156281) which may help

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, I did try grepping already for Ruby processes and killed them. So far, that hasn't fixed it! But I will take a bigger look, maybe I missed something. Cheers.

Comment: are you using bundle to manage dependencies?

Comment: Right now, I'm at the very start of this new app and all it has is a file similar to the first answer below (a sort of 'Hello world'). I do have Sinatra as a dependency and it is required by the file. So I don't know that dependencies are the problem in this case. Thanks.

Comment: what gem did you update to 2.5.0? latest sinatra is at 1.4.7

Answer (score 0):

Let's start simple, what happens when you write and run the following application in `test.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
    "Hello World!"
end
```

Then `gem install sinatra` and `ruby test.rb`. You should see something along these lines:

```
== Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

Now in a second terminal run `curl`:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:4567
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  body { text-align:center;font-family:helvetica,arial;font-size:22px;
    color:#888;margin:20px}
  #c {margin:0 auto;width:500px;text-align:left}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Sinatra doesn&rsquo;t know this ditty.</h2>
  <img src='http://localhost:4567/__sinatra__/404.png'>
  <div id="c">
    Try this:
    <pre>get &#x27;&#x2F;&#x27; do
  &quot;Hello World&quot;
end
</pre>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you do that and post the result of the curl session?

Comment: This is what I am getting back with the cURL session:

`➜  ~  curl -XGET localhost:4567
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
`

I feel like I am taking crazy pills here! What is going on? I did restart my computer that didn't fix it.

Comment: Does localhost bind to 127.0.0.1? Can you check your '/etc/hosts' and give an 'lsof -i' while running sinatra?